# Getting a list of packages installed on CentOS (by command line and on the web)

Tags: centos, installation, package-management

When installing CentOS (6.2), it installs a whole bunch of packages, but the installation is often very fast, it's hard to note the names of the packages. I have a couple of questions:

- 1) I'm guessing I could wait for the entire installation to complete and then query for the list of installed packages on the system. How do I do that?
- 2) Is there a printed list somewhere on the web, so I don't have to install the OS first just to get the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative, since many admins want to take a machine and replicate it somewhere else.

The installer will create a kickstart template of your system into `~root/anaconda-ks.cfg` , which includes the packages and package groups which were selected during the install.

This template can be used to replicate your build on another system. You can also take this template, modify it to your needs (Add a longer %postinstall section, add users, modify NICs, etc) and reimage the current system.

I have a Virtual Machine on my laptop. I wanted a minimal install, so I manually deselected all additional packages.

```
%packages --nobase
@core
%end
```

This shows that I didn't select any extra packages, and only installed the 'core' Package Group.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `yum list installed > ~/packages` from a terminal.  This will save the list of installed packages to a plain text file in your home directory.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @briankb's answer, `$ rpm -qa` will give you a list of installed packages as well.

Answer (score 3):

1. My CentOS 6.2 still has its original ~root/install.log and install.log.syslog where a catalog of installed packages at install time is produced.
2. Well if you are into customizing the packages to be installed then you can do so during the graphical install by choosing "Customize now". You will get the full list there to choose from. Quite a large list though. Note that pre/core requisites will be installed, sometimes not so obvious why. ex. why would the printing system requires a sound library? Well because it uses it to produce beeps and alerts , if you choose!!!